# Error while trying to run /home/andy/bin/python3 paste_snippets.py which is linked to the key

Tags: shortcut-keys

I made a keyboard shortcut. But I get this message when I try to run it.

```
Error while trying to run /home/andy/bin/python3 paste_snippets.py which is
linked to the key(<Primary>Alt>a)
```

Primary is really the Ctrl key.

---

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

home = os.environ["HOME"]
directory = home+"/.config/snippet_paste"
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
# create file list with snippets
files = [
    directory+"/"+item for item in os.listdir(directory) \
         if not item.endswith("~") and not item.startswith(".")
    ]
# create string list
strings = []
for file in files:
    with open(file) as src:
        strings.append(src.read())
# create list to display in option menu
list_items = ["manage snippets"]+[
    (str(i+1)+". "+strings[i].replace("\n", " ").replace\
     ('"', "'")[:20]+"..") for i in range(len(strings))
    ]
# define (zenity) option menu
test= 'zenity --list '+'"'+('" "')\
      .join(list_items)+'"'\
      +' --column="text fragments" --title="Paste snippets Ctrl V"'
# process user input
try:
    choice = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", test]).decode("utf-8")
    if "manage snippets" in choice:
        subprocess.call(["nautilus", directory])
    else:
        i = int(choice[:choice.find(".")])
        # copy the content of corresponding snippet
        copy = "xclip -in -selection c "+"'"+files[i-1]+"'"
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", copy])
        # paste into open frontmost file
        paste = "xdotool key Control_L+v"
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", paste])
except Exception:
    pass
```

[image]

It works fine in 16.04 but not in 18.04.

Am I doing something wrong?

7/18/18
When run from command line.

Even though window pops up, all I get is

```
Gtk-Message: 21:23:49.927: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent.         
This is discouraged.
```

Comment: Couple notes: 1) just use subprocess.call() function directly, no need to spawn bash 2) use os.path.join() instead of plus symbol for adding items to home or other path variables

Comment: Can you run the script from the command line?

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy Could you be more specific?

Comment: @fixit7 Instead of `subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", copy])` you should be able to just do `subprocess.call(['xclip', '-sel', 'clip', list_files])`.  And  `os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".config/snippet_paste"  )`. The advantage is that you don't have to care about adding leading backslash to `/.config/snippet_paste`, the `os.path.join()` handles that automatically

Comment: Please crop out all the unnecessary whitespace from your screenshots.

Comment: @muru Cropping done.

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace this line

```
   subprocess.call(["nautilus", directory])
```

with

```
    subprocess.call(["thunar", directory])
```

I do not have nautilus but use thunar as my file manager.